# table viewer editable with string array item

Tags: java, swt, jface

I want to make my table viewer editable. I decide to use setEditingSupport and EdittingSupport. But the table content is stored in a string array, which has no setter and getter. How can I write code in the getValue() and setValue() in the class extends EdittingSupport?
The code of the tableviewer shows below:

```
public class DatatypePage extends WizardPage
```

{

```
public static final String NAME = "type";
private MigratorWizard wizard;  

private TableViewer tableViewer;

protected DatatypePage(MigratorWizard wizard) 
{
    super(NAME);
    this.wizard = wizard;
    setTitle("Data Type");
    setDescription("This is a data type page");
}

@Override
public void createControl(Composite parent) 
{
    Composite compositeContent = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    setControl(compositeContent);

    //super.createControl(parent);
    //updatePage(rbtnDatatype);

    compositeContent.setLayout(new FormLayout());

    Button btnEditConstraint = new Button(compositeContent, SWT.NONE);
    FormData fd_btnEditConstraint = new FormData();
    fd_btnEditConstraint.left = new FormAttachment(0, 287);
    btnEditConstraint.setLayoutData(fd_btnEditConstraint);
    btnEditConstraint.setText("Edit Constraint");

    Button btnAddConstraint = new Button(compositeContent, SWT.NONE);
    fd_btnEditConstraint.top = new FormAttachment(btnAddConstraint, 0, SWT.TOP);
    fd_btnEditConstraint.right = new FormAttachment(btnAddConstraint, -63);
    FormData fd_btnAddConstraint = new FormData();
    fd_btnAddConstraint.bottom = new FormAttachment(100);
    fd_btnAddConstraint.left = new FormAttachment(0, 500);
    btnAddConstraint.setLayoutData(fd_btnAddConstraint);
    btnAddConstraint.setText("Add Constraint");
    btnAddConstraint.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override 
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        }
    });

    Button btnDeleteConstraint = new Button(compositeContent, SWT.NONE);
    fd_btnAddConstraint.right = new FormAttachment(btnDeleteConstraint, -60);

    FormData fd_btnDeleteConstraint = new FormData();
    fd_btnDeleteConstraint.left = new FormAttachment(0, 710);
    fd_btnDeleteConstraint.right = new FormAttachment(100, -2);
    fd_btnDeleteConstraint.bottom = new FormAttachment(100);
    btnDeleteConstraint.setLayoutData(fd_btnDeleteConstraint);
    btnDeleteConstraint.setText("Delete Constraint");

    btnDeleteConstraint.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            ISelection selection = tableViewer.getSelection();
            logger.debug("datatype selected");
            if (selection != null || selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
                IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
                Iterator iterator = sel.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Object obj = iterator.next();
                    tableViewer.remove(obj);
                }


            }

        }
    });


    tableViewer = new TableViewer(compositeContent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
            | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
    Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
    FormData fd_table = new FormData();
    fd_table.bottom = new FormAttachment(btnEditConstraint, -6);
    fd_table.top = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_table.left = new FormAttachment(0);
    fd_table.right = new FormAttachment(100);
    table.setLayoutData(fd_table);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    TableViewerColumn tcolOracle = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tcOracle = tcolOracle.getColumn();
    tcOracle.setText("oracle");
    tcOracle.setWidth(300);
    tcolOracle.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            String[] t = (String[]) element;
            return t[0];
        }
    });
    tcolOracle.setEditingSupport(new FirstColEdittingSupport(tableViewer));

    TableViewerColumn tcolHighgo = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn tcHighgo = tcolHighgo.getColumn();
    tcHighgo.setText("hgdb");
    tcHighgo.setWidth(300);
    tcolHighgo.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            String[] t = (String[]) element;
            return t[1];
        }
    });


    initConfig();


}

private void initConfig()
{
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider()); 
    //tableViewer.setInput(DataTypeFactory.getInstance().getCastList(wizard.getSourceInfo().getDBType()));
    // make the selection available to other views
    // getSite().setSelectionProvider(tableViewer);
}


public void update()
{
    logger.debug("sourceDB=" + wizard.getSourceInfo().getDBType());
    tableViewer.setInput(DataTypeFactory.getInstance().getCastList(wizard.getSourceInfo().getDBType()));
    logger.debug("dataType = "+ wizard.getSourceInfo().getDBType());
    tableViewer.refresh();

    // tableViewer.getTable().selectAll();
}
```

}

Comment: can you please show us some code?

Comment: this method return a List<String[]>  DataTypeFactory.getInstance().getCastList(wizard.getSourceInfo().getDBType())

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the design of the input so that it does not use just a string array. Use a class for each row containg the columns data and add get and set methods to that class.

You can either change the data you pass to `setInput` to use this class or you can use a custom content provider to do the conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean I need to create a new class for the data resource instead of call the method I used to get the data?

Comment: It is up to you where you do this. You could change `getCastList` to return a list of the row class, or you can change the list before calling `setInput` or you can make the content provider create the class instances. It just depends which makes most sense in you program.

Comment: Thanks again. But I have another question, the data stored in the string array has a mapping relation. How to keep this relationship if I would change the list?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'mapping relation'

Comment: It means 1 to 1 relationship.  And I tried to convert the element object into string array , and then, return str[index], it works.